# Laptop thinks it has proper ip but others receive connections as '169.254.xxx.xxx'

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I'm trying to assign static IPs to all the Windows pcs in my LAN network. I reserved the ips by associating them with the MAC address in my home router and everything is working fine except for **one wi-fi laptop**.

I'd like to assign it a 192.168.1.9 ip so I did the same in the router and now the laptop says, with `ipconfig`, that the IPv4 address is `192.168.1.9`.

Anyway as soon as I try to connect to other pcs in the network expecting it to have that address, the connection results from `169.254.xxx.xxx` where the `xxx` part is variable.

I did read around that this is a sign of laptop making its ip address up since there are problems communicating with router DHCP, but then why does ipconfig show the correct one?

How do I fix this? I tried resetting winsock, clearing arp cache, renewing and resetting/releasing leases via ipconfig.. nothing worked.

Comment: Where do you see the APIPA address (that's the name of this kind of addresses) if not in the ipconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a strong suspicion that you set a static IP address on the wrong interface.  Your laptop probably has two network devices.  One being the wired LAN interface and the other being WiFi.

If you are using WiFi, disable the internal NIC to make troubleshooting easier, or vice versa.